# Working with checkboxes and querying the database in Django

Tags: django, forms

My goal is to create a page that lists all the courses available in the database and have the user select which courses they would like to be a tutor for.

I have a `CustomUser` model, a `courses` model, and finally a `TutorTeachesCourse` model that takes `user` and `courses` as foreign keys.

```
# model.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
  is_tutee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_tutor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  courses = models.ManyToManyField(Courses)

class Courses(models.Model):
  course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = False)
  course_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = False)
  department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  course_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
  #tutor = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser) #moved m2m relationship to user model
  objects = models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.course_name
```

```
# forms.py
class EditTutoredCoursesForm(forms.Form):
  model = CustomUser
  course = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset = Courses.objects.all(),
    widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
  )

  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(EditTutoredCoursesForm, self).clean()
    is_tutor = cleaned_data.get('is_tutor')
    if not is_tutor:
      raise forms.ValidationError('Validation error.')

  def save(self,commit=True):
    rel=super(EditTutoredCoursesForm,self).save(commit=False)
    rel.is_tutor=self.cleaned_data['is_tutor']
    if commit:
      rel.save()
    return rel
```

```
# views.py
def edit_tutored_courses(request):
  user = request.user
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditTutoredCoursesForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      user.courses.set(form.cleaned_data['courses'])
      user = form.save(commit=True)
      messages.success(request, 'Success!')
    return redirect(reverse('view_profile'))
  else:
    form = EditTutoredCoursesForm()
  context = {
    'form' : form,
  }
  return render(request, 'edit_tutored_courses.html', context)
```

And here the page where the user selects/unselects the courses they wish to tutor/not tutor.

```
# edit_tutored_courses.html
<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
  <th>Course Name</th>
</tr>
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for is_tutor in form %}
{% for course in is_tutor %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ course }}</td>
  <td>{{ user }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
</form>
```

I can display the courses on my page but I don't know how to make changes to the database. I want the checkboxes to mean that once I click "submit" the table `TutorTeachesCourses` populates with that user with the checked courses, and if I uncheck the boxes it means it deletes the existing one. (That means I also need to make the page automatically check the boxes that exists int he database. How do I do all of this?

Comment: So, what's the problem/question?

Comment: Use a regular `Form` (not `ModelForm`) with a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) and a `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget. You'll need to change your template to display that field instead of looping through the courses. Then in your view, the value of the field cleaned data will be the list of courses, so you can then create your relationships.

Comment: Note that you could have just defined a `ManyToManyField` on `Course` to `CustomUser` instead of creating a separate model.

Comment: @dirkgroten From my understanding, `Form` is useful if there are changes to be made to the database through models. Since I will be writing changes for every submit clicked, wouldn't it be useful to use `ModelForm` in this case?

Comment: @dirkgroten and thanks for the tip on ManyToMany, totally forgot about that! edited post to reflect changes made

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202952/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-herrypotter).

Comment: @dirkgroten when I use `Form` instead of `ModelForm` I get an error `object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: `if form.is_valid(): user.courses.set(form.cleaned_data['courses’]` is all you need to do to assign the selected courses.

Comment: @dirkgroten how would I print each course name on the page? I'm getting `Courses object (3)` by the checkmark when I loop over the form.

Comment: Add a __str__() method to your model. That’s what’s used for printing objects.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm getting the html page to load as I want, thank you for that! But hitting the submit button does not make the changes. Getting `{{ user.courses }}` does shows there is no relationship between course and user after I click submit with some checkmarks selected. I also placed the manytomany relationship in CustomUser because it seems more logical in this case (logged in user want to add-remove courses to their list), but that shouldn't be the reason why it's not adding.